# "Event is raised when maintenance occurs or scheduled" vs. "or is scheduled"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, parallelism

Which sentence is correct?

> - Event is raised when maintenance occurs or scheduled.
> - Event is raised when maintenance occurs or **is** scheduled.

Comment: Those sentences should possibly start with ***An** event...*.

Comment: This question is a better fit for our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). The first sentence is clearly ungrammatical and extremely unlikely to be produced by a native speaker even as a one-off error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different verbs have different *transitivity*, which means that some can take no direct object, some one, some more, and some are flexible in this regard.

*Occur* is an intransitive verb, and takes no object, so we can say "maintenance occurs".

*Schedule* is a transitive verb, that must take a direct object. So we cannot say "maintenance schedules" here as that means that the maintenance is what does the scheduling. You can though say "the engineer schedules maintenance". ("maintenance schedules" also leaves us wondering what it schedules. Even "The engineer schedules" is a stretch of the word, as it really should have an object).

We can though use a transitive verb in the passive voice, so the subject becomes the thing acted upon rather than the thing acting: "maintenance is scheduled".

Put together:

> An event is raised when maintenance occurs or is scheduled.

Answer (score 6):

You need to say *is scheduled*, because *schedule* cannot be used intransitively.